# Can't boot after 14.04 upgrade

Tags: boot, 14.04, system-installation, desktop-environments

Dual boot from 2 hard drives (win7, U13.10). Been running good for months (year?). Auto upgraded to 14.04 over night. Got up in the morning, and it won't boot into Ubuntu. It says it can't find the root directory and systems on boot, and won't let me type any commands.

I built a 14.04 USB stick, and running that right now.
The stick is able to mount the target harddrive and I am able to recover the files that I have permission to access (?) of folders I am allowed to see the contents. I've been able to save my most essential files (invoices, tax info, accounting, order tracker); but some other random ones are not able to be copied over to the other harddrive.

The stick is not able to install 14.04 to the desired HD because the root file system is not defined. It appears as one giant partition on the installer tool. I don't know what to do to re-part while avoiding wiping out my files.

So the question:
How do I get it to install 14.04, without losing my files? Thanks!!